# Reading exact table definition with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to import a database table for data analysis using Pandas.  I have a source table with multiple columns like so:

```
ID float NOT NULL, 
Name varchar(36) NOT NULL,
Address varchar(100)
```

When I pull it into a dataframe and run the following:

```
df.info()
```

I get:

```
ID float64
Name object
Address object
```

Is there a way to get it to read the exact data defintion?  i.e.  "varchar(36)" instead of "object".

This is reading from a Teradata table, if that makes a difference

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, this is not possible. The `varchar` data type exists in the Teradata database system only, and is casted to a sensible pandas data type (`str` or `unicode`) once you pull it into a DataFrame.

An overview of data types in pandas, numpy, and python: http://pbpython.com/pandas_dtypes.html

Comment: thanks, that link helps.  I think I may be out of luck with that particular task, unless there is something else besides Pandas that may work?  I have bookmarked that link you sent, good info

Answer (score 1):

pandas relies of numpy data types.

Visit the [related part of the pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dtypes) which has more information into it but I'll copy all the types from there:

```
[numpy.generic,
 [[numpy.number,
   [[numpy.integer,
     [[numpy.signedinteger,
       [numpy.int8,
        numpy.int16,
        numpy.int32,
        numpy.int64,
        numpy.int64,
        numpy.timedelta64]],
      [numpy.unsignedinteger,
       [numpy.uint8,
        numpy.uint16,
        numpy.uint32,
        numpy.uint64,
        numpy.uint64]]]],
    [numpy.inexact,
     [[numpy.floating,
       [numpy.float16, numpy.float32, numpy.float64, numpy.float128]],
      [numpy.complexfloating,
       [numpy.complex64, numpy.complex128, numpy.complex256]]]]]],
  [numpy.flexible,
   [[numpy.character, [numpy.bytes_, numpy.str_]],
    [numpy.void, [numpy.record]]]],
  numpy.bool_,
  numpy.datetime64,
  numpy.object_]]
```

The bottom line is, I cannot see any dtype that would support to show something similar to varchar(#). The default of handling strings is to assing them dtype "object" in pandas framework.

In Python in general, you don't have fixed or semi-fixed size string as far as my knowledge goes (you can do fixed size formatting for printing, though).